# How to calculate confidence interval

Tags: r, confidence-interval

We are supposed to find the 90% confidence interval for a 74 year old man.

`x <- c(58, 69, 43, 39, 63, 52, 47, 31, 74, 36)`
`y <- c(189, 235, 193, 177, 154, 191, 213, 165, 198, 181)`
(where x is age and y is cholesterol level)
i used:
`correlation <- cor.test(x, y, conf.level = 0.90)`

and that gives me this:

`data:  x and y t = 1.2656, df = 8, p-value = 0.2413 alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0 90 percent confidence interval: -0.1857867  0.7839057 sample estimates: cor 0.4084309`

and when i asked people in my class what values they were getting all of them told me (203.2717, 205.5591) Where am I going wrong, the corr.test is telling me -0.1857867  0.7839057.

also the next portion of the assignment is asking us to calculate a 90% prediction interval for a 74 year olds, how would i do this in r studio?
thanks a lot!

Comment: The 95% confidence interval for what?  I'm guessing the predicted cholesterol level for a 75 year old man based on a regression of cholesterol on age (and sex?).  If so, you need to do a regression.  And find the sex of each of the people/observations in your dataset.  You can tell your answer is wrong because the CI is completely outside the data range for both `x` and `y`.  That doesn't seem right, does it?

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(58, 69, 43, 39, 63, 52, 47, 31, 74, 36),
  y = c(189, 235, 193, 177, 154, 191, 213, 165, 198, 181)
)

predict.lm(
  lm(y~x, data = df), 
  newdata = data.frame(x = 74), 
  interval = "confidence", 
  level = 0.90
)

#      fit    lwr    upr
# 1 204.42 178.99 229.85
```